# AVAudioFoundation issues when volume property is set

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am writing a class which will be initialized for background audio.

```
`class BackgroundAudio: NSObject,AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer

    override init() {
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
        super.init()
    }
```

There is a function that mute the background audio in the class:

```
func mute() {
    audioPlayer.setVolume(0, fadeDuration: 2)
}
```

Because a few View Controller in this project may need to control the volume, so I put the initialization in the `AppDelegate` file like this:

```
var backgroundAudioPlayer = BackgroundAudio()
```

There is an issue when I `mute()` is called
[image]

I have been debugging this a bit time, getting stuck at the moment.  How to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you refer this, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1643591-setvolume

Comment: @KAR I did, this error looks like the auidoplayer is not initialized when the mute is pressed

Comment: How do you access this `backgroundAudioPlayer`? Please include all the relevant parts of the code in your question.

Comment: @Sam_M backgroundAudioPlayer.mute() This is how I call the method in the view controller

Comment: Is `audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()` the only place you initialise your audio player? audio player should be initialised with either a URL or Data before you call mute.

Comment: @Sam_M Cheers man, it works. I just forget to initialize the instance before I set the volume. silly me

Answer (score 0):

I’m positive that u can do this in the info setting rather than writing code....

Comment: What do you mean by info setting? I am quite confused what do you mean. Pls explain